# Как можно отправлять скриншот в телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, selenium

У меня автоматизация,как можно реализовать отправку скриншота из папки(который делает selenium),чтобы телеграм бот присылал мне фото,я решал капчу на скриншоте,отправлял обратно боту и селениум уже дальше вводил капчу в окно

Comment: капча в текстовом формате(быквы цыфры)

Answer (score 0):

После того как селениум сфотографировал, объявите переменную с исключительным путем к фотографии например `file_name`

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file_name)
```

Тут бот уже отправил Вам фотографию.
Далее бот должен принять ваш текст чтобы селениум решил капчу

Далее, переменная которую вы уже объявляли ранее, где передали `message.text`, селениум должен именно ее вписать в капчу.

Примерно так я бы сделал.
И вообще селениум не для ботов, а для тестеров